# ColorDialog - How can I check if cancel or X has been pressed

Tags: powershell

In this PowerShell code, the dialog opens but I cannot seem to find a way to know if the cancel or X button has been pressed.

If the user presses cancel then there's a returned value from the `Color` property.

How can I fix this so that it will return something different if the user presses cancel or X to close the dialog.

```
$colorDialog = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog
[void]$colorDialog.ShowDialog()

# This will always return a value even when cancel is pressed.
$colorDialog.Color
```

It always returns this if cancel or the X button has been pressed:

```
R             : 0
G             : 0
B             : 0
A             : 255
IsKnownColor  : True
IsEmpty       : False
IsNamedColor  : True
IsSystemColor : False
Name          : Black
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inspect the [result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dialogresult?view=net-5.0) returned from `ShowDialog()`:

```
$colorDialog = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog
if($colorDialog.ShowDialog() -eq 'OK'){
  $colorDialog.Color
} 
else {
  Write-Warning "No color was picked"
}
```